# Executing a function daily in background in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm building a weekly todo list app where users can check off items once completed. And I need the list(table) to refresh daily to get rid of the checkmarks. How could I go about creating a function that goes off at a certain time every day?
I'm currently using UserDefaults to store the list items, etc.

Thank you,

Comment: i decided to use Date() and compare the current date to previously accessed date!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a Cron Job or a process to be executed every day at midnight. It depends on which computer/operating system you are using.

Unless its just a UI thing you can do

```
if (checked_at + 24hours > now) then uncheck
```

Comment: ive considered using the "checking if it has been 24 hours since the last checked time" method but the only problem with that is it doesn't necessarily reset it the next day (like monday, tuesday)...it resets after 24 hours.

Comment: ok you can check if its a different date then 
`if var (new Date()).getDate() != old_date`